# Add appointment to calendar through Exchange programatically

Tags: exchange-server

How can I add an item to a users calendar programatically through the Exchange 2003 Information Store.  I need to know the interface or connector to research. I have full Exchange rights and want to be able to automate assigning appointments without the end users interaction or login.  I know this is possible as I have a 3rd party enterprise app that does this very thing.

Any guidance would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

There are [CDO (Collaboration Data Objects)](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/Dot_Net_2005.aspx) and Exchange Web Services

Comment: Use CDO for Exchange 2003 and EWS for 2007/2010.  Btw, EWS is MUCH easier than CDO.